# TTImageView with urlPath from Amazon S3

Tags: objective-c, ios, amazon-s3, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I get error when loading images from a urlPath that comes from S3 Amazon, is this a problem with three20?

I get the urlPath by the way from a web service..

the web service has a script that checks something from me then returns the image of my request if i'm a valid user.. (something to do for security)

when I manually load the image url path i receive from my web service in a web browser, it loads normally, but why wont it load in the TTImageView?

Answer (score 2):

I use the `TTImageView` with images loaded directly from amazon S3 and I haven't had any issues with it.

I use the S3 domain mapping feature amazon offer, so the images URLs have my domain address in them (http://assets.domainname.com/image.jpeg).

Tutorial : http://www.brangle.com/wordpress/2010/11/mapping-amazon-aws-s3-to-a-custom-domain-name/

Comment: I think, i would really dive into this since, I dont directly access the file, thanks though :)

Comment: This is super helpful - sorry to necro but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Is your bucket new? New EU buckets (not sure about US) redirect urls to `S3-external-3.amazonaws.com` until the dns settings are properly setup.

Perhaps `TTImageView` is not following the redirect.

Comment: ill try to talk with my teammate about this, since i'm not working on this alone, thanks man :)

Comment: i got an NSURLErrorDomain btw, is this a settings problem in the server already?

Comment: @BacalsoVincent - Can you provide a sample url or at least the format of the url. Is your bucket in the US or EU?

Comment: I work with an api, and it gives me this path: this is just a sample path btw https://www.mydomain.com/filename.php/more/folders/here/the_image.jpg

Comment: @BacalsoVincent - Am I missing something? That doesn't look like an Amazon S3 url. Is it a php endpoint/service that redirects to the S3 url? What is `filename.php`?

Comment: the 'filename.php' file btw is a script that will get the image, this is done for security purposes

Comment: the api also returns a url of amazon, and it's in US

Comment: @BacalsoVincent - Ok, I imagine this is the cause of your problems. Have you tried some sort of traffic analyzer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on windows to see what is going on? If security is a concern, have you considered making your images private and serving them with [time expiring urls](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html)?

Comment: I dont really understand those stuffs, I asked my teammate that the url given is not direct to the actual file itself, rather, that php file is responsible for creating the file.

Comment: @BacalsoVincent - So the php script is retriving the file from Amazon and serving it to the client. Basically a proxy. Then I guess you should check that the php script is returning the correct mime-type, headers etc.

Comment: yes it is correct since the image is display when the link is accessed in the browser,but it will create an error when the same link is used in three20

Comment: anyway thanks a lot mate; too bad i really don't have idea on the server side